# Return new line in QR code scanner in PHP

Tags: php, qr-code

So after search the questions available in here, I still cannot find the solution for breaking new line when users scan the code.

I already try \n, PHP_EOL but still can't managed to solve it.

```
<?php
$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$pass = 'db_pass';
$name = 'db_name';

$i = 0;
$q = $r = $s ="";
$data = $data2 = array();
$con = new mysqli($host,$user,$pass,$name);
    if($con->connect_error)
        die ("Error: ".$con->connect_error);
    $pid = ($_POST['pid']);
        $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM purchase_detail WHERE purchase_id ='$pid' ");

 $b=mysqli_num_rows($result);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        
        $data[$i] = $row['type_id'];
        $data2[$i] = $row ['quantity'];
        $i++;
    }
    
        
    
    for ($x = 0; $x < $b; $x++) 
    {   
    $q .= $data[$x];
    $r .= $data2[$x];
    $s .='Type: '.$q[$x] .' Quantity: '.$r[$x];
    echo ''.PHP_EOL.'';
    } 
 
echo "<img src='qr_img.php?d=$s'";


?>

<html>
    <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="pid">
    </form>
</html>
```

The result for current is:

```
Type: 1 Quantity: 1Type: 2 Quantity: 1Type: 3 Quantity: 1Type: 4 Quantity: 1
```

But, I would like it appear like this:

```
Type: 1 Quantity: 1
Type: 2 Quantity: 1
Type: 3 Quantity: 1
Type: 4 Quantity: 1
```

Example:
[QR Scanner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LsL5m.png)

I use CodeTwo Desktop QR reader for scanning the QR code.

EDITED:
If I used '\n':

```
for ($x = 0; $x < $b; $x++) 
{   
 $q .= $data[$x];
 $r .= $data2[$x];
 $s .='Type: '.$q[$x] .' Quantity: '.$r[$x];
 echo '\n';
}
```

[Result of '\n'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jonw7.png)

Comment: What do you mean by "breaking new line when users scan the code"? Also, be warned that your SQL query is open for SQL injection - better use prepared statements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After google-ing for days, I found the answer below:

```
for ($x = 0; $x < $b; $x++) 
{   
$q .= $data[$x];
$r .= $data2[$x];
$s .='Type: '.$q[$x] .' Quantity: '.$r[$x].'%0A';
}
```

Simply `%0A`

Comment: Your Solution worked for me like a charm.... Thanks buddy incognitorrrr

Answer (score 0):

Try with `<br />` tag

```
for ($x = 0; $x < $b; $x++) 
{   
    $q .= $data[$x];
    $r .= $data2[$x];
    $s .='Type: '.$q[$x] .' Quantity: '.$r[$x];
    echo "<br />";
}
```

Your output is HTML but if you put `plain text` then \n will work like following

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/plain');
echo "abc\nxyz";
?>
```

And remember `\n` will work inside double quote like this `"\n"` not `'\n'`. Because double quote evaluates variable and other special chars.

When you run your **PHP** on browser, by default it will render HTML not plain text, you need to specify the content type. So in your case \n will not work.

**Edited Solution for you:**

```
for ($x = 0; $x < $b; $x++) 
{   
 $q .= $data[$x];
 $r .= $data2[$x];
 $s .='Type: '.$q[$x] .' Quantity: '.$r[$x];
 echo "<br />"; //because your output page is html type not plain text type
}
```

**And if you put your page content type as** `header('Content-type: text/plain');`

```
for ($x = 0; $x < $b; $x++) 
{   
 $q .= $data[$x];
 $r .= $data2[$x];
 $s .='Type: '.$q[$x] .' Quantity: '.$r[$x];
 echo "\n"; //for content type text/plain
}
```

**Note:** In your `result snapshot`, your problem is this, but use `"<br />"` because html content type

```
echo '\n'; <----------- Will be treated as simply a string that contains \n
echo "\n"; <----------- Will be treated as a line break, not string
```

Comment: put \n inside double quote like `"\n"` not `'\n'`........why dont you use `echo "<br>" there because your output is in html type not plain text type. If your page output is in plain text then only \n will work. But \n must be put inside double quote not single quote though.

Comment: PHP treat single quoted `\n` as simply string so use "\n" , where double quote will evaluate your code inside that.

Comment: Actually, this is not about web html. This coding just to display QRcode in the web browser. After QR code being display, I will scan it using this :https://www.codetwo.com/freeware/qr-code-desktop-reader/ . So i want to break a new line in that scanner.

Comment: yes i got you use echo "<br />" instead of \n. please read my post. please read this post carefully. I know you just want new line and i have posted many ways in this answer. Or you just want me to post all code??

Comment: I got the answer already. Thanks anyway for guiding me with patience :D